# How do I run software after I install it with make install?

Tags: linux, installation, make

I downloaded a `tar.gz` for the Player Project from Sourceforge. I ran the make install command to install it, and got no errors. But I don't know how to actually run the program. There are multiple .exe files relating to it in the `/usr/local/bin` folder. However, nothing happens when I attempt to run them with Wine. I tried running the `player.exe` file from the terminal and I get this error -

> player: error while loading shared libraries: libplayerdrivers.so.3.0:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I get that it’s obviously saying I am missing a file, but I don't know what to do about it. I tried reinstalling it and still get the error. Is this something wrong with the `tar.gz` I downloaded or am I doing something wrong to run it?

Comment: .exe files in a Linux program?

Comment: This is more applicable to superuser.com, or ubuntu.stackexchange.com (or unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I was reading at and stopped at ".exe files in /usr.." - then I started being "WTF?!?"

Comment: @mathepic and halfdan: From his statement it looks like he is running Wine, which is a type of Windows emulation.  Wine allows you to run certain exe files.

Comment: @linuxuser27 Except why would you use a `make install` for a Windows program?

Comment: Maybe you are missing `/usr/local/lib/whatever` from your `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: @linuxuser: WINE = Wine Is Not an Emulator ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you `./configure/make/make install`
you should just be able to run them from the command line. If they end with .exe and they are Linux native(seems like it), then they are mono executables.

The thing about the .so implies you are missing the needed shared library.

Answer (score 0):

On Debian (should be the same on Ubuntu or other Debian-based distributions):

```
$ apt-file search libplayerdrivers
libplayerdrivers3.0: /usr/lib/libplayerdrivers.so.3.0  
libplayerdrivers3.0: /usr/lib/libplayerdrivers.so.3.0.1  
libplayerdrivers3.0: /usr/share/doc/libplayerdrivers3.0/changelog.Debian.gz  
libplayerdrivers3.0: /usr/share/doc/libplayerdrivers3.0/changelog.gz  
libplayerdrivers3.0: /usr/share/doc/libplayerdrivers3.0/copyright  
libplayerdrivers3.0-dev: /usr/include/player-3.0/libplayerdrivers/driverregistry.h  
libplayerdrivers3.0-dev: /usr/lib/libplayerdrivers.so  
libplayerdrivers3.0-dev: /usr/share/doc/libplayerdrivers3.0-dev/changelog.Debian.gz  
libplayerdrivers3.0-dev: /usr/share/doc/libplayerdrivers3.0-dev/changelog.gz  
libplayerdrivers3.0-dev: /usr/share/doc/libplayerdrivers3.0-dev/copyright  
robot-player-doc: /usr/share/doc/player/html/group__libplayerdrivers.html`
```

...so maybe you just need to install `libplayerdrivers3.0`. When you `./configure`, the script should really warn you about missing libraries, but that script might be defect.

I'm not sure of what program installs `.exe` files in your directory structure and requires you to use `wine` to run them, but closing my eyes to that, the above written is the first thing I'd try.